# Overwrite Chrome option mid test

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I would like to test a single scenario that something appears when JS is disabled.  I only want JS removed for this one scenario.

Can I temporarily overwrite a chrome setting?

My env.rb looks like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    opts.add_argument '--start-maximized'
    opts.add_argument '--disable-infobars'
    opts.add_argument '--headless' if Settings.browser.headless
    opts.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
    unless Settings.browser.sandbox
      opts.add_argument '--no-sandbox'
      opts.add_argument '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    end
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true)
    caps.browser_name = 'chrome'
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   browser: :chrome,
                                   options: opts,
                                   desired_capabilities: caps)
  end
```

I would like to overwrite the setting to disable Javascript.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not split off your JavaScript-less tests into another test case with different driver settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the current drivers settings mid run, but you can register another driver and use it for just the one scenario.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_no_js do |app|
  ... # setup driver with the desired options, etc
end
```

Then in your features, assuming you're using the normal Capybara/Cucumber config, you can tag your scenario to use the new driver

```
@chrome_no_js
Scenario: do something with js disabled
...
```

Note: there's no guarantee everything will work correctly with JS disabled since Capybara has to use JS to work around bugs/limitations...

Comment: How would you disable javascript in the driver?  I have tried ```opts.add_argument --disable-javascript'``` and ```caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true, javascript_enabled: false)``` - Neither are working

Comment: @Tom I don't know -- definitely used to be `--disable-javascript` as a command line argument, but it's highly possible they've removed the option, or you're having a conflict because you're using options and capabilities